# MongoDB - Only using find method to limit filtered age in the projection

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query

I have the following BSON data:

```
[
  {
    "test": 1,
    "arr": [
      {
        age: 24,
        name: "a"
      },
      {
        age: 55,
        name: "b"
      },
      {
        age: 12,
        name: "c"
      },
      {
        age: 14,
        name: "d"
      },
      {
        age: 67,
        name: "e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible by using only the `find` method to get the "age" field inside the `arr` array which is less than 30 for each array element?

So my expected output:

```
[
  {
    "test": 1,
    "arr": [
      {
        age: 24,
        name: "a"
      }
      {
        age: 12,
        name: "c"
      },
      {
        age: 14,
        name: "d"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It would be great too if it is possible with one find to flatten the array.

Comment: If you want to flatten the array, you need to do it on your back-end [Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgDgVzAZwgXggbQFAQgb1zwgCIwRkwSAuCARgBoi8SBDAJ3Zq2eMOIERWAcxC0ATABYmg4jFYBbMaVYleeAL4zB-WUNG0647bPlLaJAMZrZW9QXt4RyutMcQzykgBMbgjbwAukQBgQDc2NigkABmwKxg5DAAgpy0rDAAnpiB6FjhUeAQ7BQIwJAYsIgoAHQxAPbsAKKslgAWABQAHugAfA540QQc7AwQNRP1AEYAVhp5XRFEDewQHUPeCawQ9TFCnACUA8RxCUmp7DWIyJ3445OzYyO0m2CsGgcRmtgfS5b1MGQ9VANWA9WEHVOiRAKUOYSAA). Or using [aggregation query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ZbV0R3WHiv) with `$unwind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to filter the element(s) in an array in the projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  "arr.age": {
    $lt: 30
  }
},
{
  "test": 1,
  "arr": {
    $filter: {
      input: "$arr",
      cond: {
        $lt: [
          "$$this.age",
          30
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kcRs9rQbgLf)

Comment: Thank you. May I ask aggregation is better in this case or still findOne is quicker?

Comment: Hi, it is not comparable between the performance of the aggregation and `find` query. It depends on how your data collection size, query performance, any index applied to the collection, the query utilizes the index, etc. When you use the aggregation query, you need the `{ $limit: 1 }` stage to return a document. While the `findOne` is equivalent to `db.collection.find(/* filter criteria */).limit(1)`

Comment: Thank you. You code is really nice but I never thought I even could do it with only find method.

Comment: The `find` query is used for filtering and getting data (simple query). The aggregation query is used when you want to do some complex query (calculation, transformation), working with the aggregation operators.